# Have vertical bar right next to form entry

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a webpage where it is a form, but the employee id is separated from the rest of the form by a vertical bar that spans the entire page. [image: 1] However, when I try to do that with a green vertical bar, it looks like [image: 2]. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
.vl {
    border-left: 6px solid green;
    height: 500px;
  }

<label htmlFor='ID'>EMPLOYEE #</label>
<input className="form-control w-25" id="ID" readOnly></input>
<div className="vl"></div>
<form data-transport-order="form">
<div className="form-group">
<label htmlFor='ID'>Invoice No.</label>
<input className="form-control" id="ID" readOnly></input>
<label htmlFor="TransportDate">Date</label>
<input type="date" className="form-control w-25" ID="TransportDate" autoFocus required></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied. Should the 'class' in that div actually be className given you are using React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using flex it's easier and a good fit of this case.

Your component JSX:

```
<div className='form-container'>
    <div className='employee-id'>
        <label htmlFor='ID'>EMPLOYEE #</label>
        <input className="form-control w-25" id="ID" readOnly></input>
    </div>
    <form className='employee-details' data-transport-order="form">
        <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor='ID'>Invoice No.</label>
        <input className="form-control" id="ID" readOnly></input>
        <label htmlFor="TransportDate">Date</label>
        <input type="date" className="form-control w-25" id="TransportDate" autoFocus required></input>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.form-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.employee-id{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 6px solid green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.employee-details .form-group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Result

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>    
    .form-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .employee-id {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      border-right: 6px solid green;
      margin-right: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .employee-details .form-group {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="App">
      <div class="form-container">
        <div class="employee-id"><label for="ID">EMPLOYEE #</label><input class="form-control w-25" id="ID" readonly=""></div>
        <form class="employee-details" data-transport-order="form">
          <div class="form-group"><label for="ID">Invoice No.</label><input class="form-control" id="ID" readonly=""><label for="TransportDate">Date</label><input type="date" class="form-control w-25" id="TransportDate" required=""></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Thank you so much!!! I'm always forgetting flex :')